# PCI-DSS : Sending antivirus logs from private infrastructure to public cloud?

Tags: pci-dss, pci-scope

We are planning to build an environment where all the Linux machines in private infrastructures will send their ClamAV log files to ELK stack hosted in a public cloud for log analysis. Is this PCI compliant?

Comment: PCI is for payments, right? Will your ClamAV log files have payment data?

Comment: That seems to be a legal question.

Comment: The answer depend of what is in the logs. If you have only "public" data in PCI point of view you can send them where you want that becomes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the logs are originating from machines that contain payment data, then your elk stack would be in scope and have to adhere to all pci requirements, as well as anything that interacts with it.